# Saving figure by creating new folder

Tags: python, plot, directory, figure

I am currently saving my plots in a folder by manually creating it. But I want to create folder automatically and save the figure in it.
My current code looks like this

```
plt.savefig('Figures_Voltage/Pack voltage.png')
```

Figures_Voltage is the folder which I created manually where there is .py file, but I want that folder to be created by Python.
Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance

Comment: `os.makedirs('Figures_Voltage", exist_ok=True)` - it creates folder if it doesn't exist and skip if exists (without error). If you remove `exist_ok` then it will rasie error if folder already exists. See also `os.mkdir()` with `os.path.exists()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if folder doesn't exists and create it

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('Figures_Voltage'):
    os.mkdir('Figures_Voltage')
```

If you try to create when it already exists then it will raise error.

---

Or use `makedirs` with `exist_ok=True` to skip it if folder already exists (without raising error)

```
os.makedirs('Figures_Voltage', exist_ok=True)
```

[makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) can also create `folder/subfolder/subsubfolder` at once.